# Where is the bug in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I run a simple project (docker-compose and nginx), but it don't work and I do not know why. I include the entire code of the project so as not to miss anything.

My project includes:

- docker-compose.yaml
- data
- - nginx.conf
- website
- - index.php

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    networks:
       - network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  website:
    image: php:7.4-fpm
    container_name: website
    volumes:
      - ./website:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "3000"
    networks:
       - network
networks:
  networks:
    driver: bridge
```

index.php:

```
   <html>
    <body>
       Body of site
    </body>
   </html>
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream site {
  server website:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name .test.ru;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name test.ru www.test.ru;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://website:3000;
  }
}
```

I don't understand how to solve it. The logs (command "docker-compose logs nginx-proxy") show only requests from the client. That is, requests reach, but the page is not loaded.

But I need my static page to open. Also I can upload the project if nginx.conf:

```
server {
  return  301 http://google.com;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what it is that isn't working and what you're doing when you test it?

Comment: Try to change "3000" in the `docker-compose.yml` to `3000:3000` and to change `expose` to `ports` as well

Comment: Hans Kilian, I wrote about how I tried to test (at least useful attempts). Now I don't know how else to try to test the project.

Comment: Dominik Lovetinsky, unfortunately it didn't help(

Comment: `proxy_pass` expects the backend to be serving HTTP, but php-fpm serves something different.  Does changing that line to `fastcgi_pass website:9000;` work any better?

Comment: @David Maze, unfortunately it didn't help( I tried  also port 3000.

Comment: Since you're serving PHP files, you should pass PHP arguments. I suggest see the unchanged `default.conf` for `nginx` and change your directive correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't use `proxy_pass` with the `php-fpm` docker image because it doesn't provide an http server but it implements fastcgi protocol instead (if you need more about [FastCGI Process Manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)).

You can try to replace your `nginx.conf` by :

```
upstream site {
  server website:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name test.ru;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name test.ru www.test.ru;
  root /var/www/html;  // You need to define where is your static files directory

  location / {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass site; // You can use your upstream here
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```